# Why is that my oldest daughter doesn’t want to give us grandchildren?

Tags: parents, grandparents

I have three daughters with my wife. I want a grandchild from my oldest daughter. I have grandchildren from my youngest two. We want a grandchild, whether a boy or girl from her. She said no. What might be the reason?

Comment: Welcome to Parenting SE. It's a tough situation, but how can we possibly know your daughter better than you do? That said, my one frame challenge would be to assume that if she doesn't want kids it's probably because of how she wants to live her own life, rather than because she wants to spite you for some reason. There are lots of reasons why people choose not to have kids -- try a Google search and many results will come up.

Comment: Not everybody wants kids, i don't get it either but it's their choice and you shouldn't try to convince them otherwise

Comment: We can't *possibly* know the answer to that. Please take the tour and see the help section for what kind of questions are on topic here. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to show her how much joy and wonder it brings to be a parent? (Sorry for sounding sappy). There are a lot of things people can do instead of having a child, you could try to motivate her by showing how rewarding it is to have a child anyway. Just because you want one will not do the trick.

Comment: Giving you grandchildren would mean giving herself - or burdening herself with - children of her own.

Comment: I'm shocked that no one has mentioned this. "What might be the reason?" Why not just ask her for yourself? She can give you an actual answer vs speculation here.

Answer (score 5):

The reasons could be many - ranging from wanting a different life, having different ambitions to maybe medical ones.

But, whatever the case, you have to understand that she's not living her life for your fulfillment, but for hers.

Comment: Well, what options do you have for me?

Comment: @TonyByrd - That's a different question.

Comment: @TonyByrd sadly for you, it's her choice. If she doesn't want to have grandkids, celebrate her as a child and celebrate your existing grandkids as grandkids. Her decision should not affect how you feel about her/treat her. You might look up information on "childfree" adults to gain some perspective into her decision.